# how to conditionally choose module dependency or source code in the app?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-library

In an android app, it has a lib module (`lib-module`) which could be used by other app or lib. And in this app it uses this lib module but directly with code:

```
include ':app', ':lib-module'
project(':lib-module').projectDir = new File(settingsDir, 'libModule')
```

there is a case that a different lib/sdk is using this `lib-module` (call it `third-rd-lib` here), so the `third-rd-lib` has dependency to a version of published `lib-module`.

and this `app` also has dependency on that `third-rd-lib`. now in the `app` the code of `lib-module` may not be in sync if the  `third-rd-lib` is using a released version of `lib-module` which is not same as the code currently in the `app`'s  `lib-module`.

question, is there a way in the app to configure the build so that it could be build either using the source code of the `lib-module`, or using dependency on the version of released `lib-module`?

**update the question**

actually I am confused. when there are both the

```
include ':app', ':lib-module'
project(':lib-module').projectDir = new File(settingsDir, 'libModule')
```

and

```
implementation "com.android.lib:third-rd-lib:x.y.z" 
// which has dependency on the lib-module:1.2.0
```

then when running the app, will the code from the dependency `lib-module:1.2.0` get loaded or the source code of the `lib-module` in the `app` is loaded?

Answer (score 0):

the [doc](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/resolution_rules.html) and [this one](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.artifacts.DependencySubstitutions.html) helped, and using this works

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.dependencySubstitution {
        substitute module('com.android.app:lib-module') with project(':lib-module')
    }
```